# Django1.8 select2 Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

This is what `Django-Select2(4.3.1)` documentations says:

> According to the select2 documentation, in order to get the
>   placeholder and allowClear settings working, you have to specify an
>   empty `<option></option>` as the first entry in your `<select>` list.

It was working fine before upgrading to `Django 1.8`.

This is what I am doing:

```
class OptionMultiChoices(AutoModelSelect2MultipleField):
    queryset = QuestionOption.objects
    search_fields = ['name__icontains', ]

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    options = OptionMultiChoices(
        widget=AutoHeavySelect2MultipleWidget(
            select2_options={
               'width': '220px',
               'placeholder': 'Lookup Options',
            }),
        required=False
    )
```

This is what I am getting:[image]

Problems in UI:

1)`Options` above the `autocomplete text box`.

2)`AutoComplete suggestions` at the bottom of page.

Answer (score 0):

Circles beside of list items refer to this reality that select2 css files not included in your template, I think your problem can solve after adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_select2/css/all.min.css">
```

In head of your template :-)